# Prune unreachable sections of a directed graph

Tags: c++, performance, graph

I have a graph represented with an Adjacency set similar to:

```cpp
struct Vertex {
    int x;
    bool operator==(const Vertex& b) {
        return x==b.x;
    }
};

template<> struct std::hash<Vertex> {
    std::size_t operator()(Vertex const& v) const noexcept {
        return std::hash<int>()(v.x);
    }
};


struct Edge {
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr;
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to;
    double weight;
    Edge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr_in, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to_in) : fr(fr_in), to(to_in) {};
};


class Graph{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> addVertex() {
        auto new_vertex = std::make_shared<Vertex>();
        mAdjacencySet[new_vertex] = {};
        return new_vertex;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Edge> addEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to) {
        auto edge = std::make_shared<Edge>(fr, to);
        mAdjacencySet[fr][to] = edge;
        return edge;
    }
    void deleteVertex(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> v) {
        mAdjacencySet.erase(v);
        for (auto& [key, val] : mAdjacencySet) {
            val.erase(v);
        }
    };
private:
    std::unordered_map<
        std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
        std::unordered_map<
            std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
            std::shared_ptr<Edge>,
            Deref::Hash,
            Deref::Compare
        >,
        Deref::Hash,
        Deref::Compare
    > mAdjacencySet;
};
```

After I build my graph, I need to prune as many edges as possible because they are expensive to calculate.

One of the strategies to do so, is to delete any vertices without any outward edges (out degree of zero). This is very slow to do, relative to the rest of my program.

I wrote a script to time the relative parts of the complexity of each part:

```
int main() {
    Timer wholeProgram;
    wholeProgram.start();

    Graph g;
    auto v1 = g.addVertex();
    auto v2 = g.addVertex();
    auto e = g.addEdge(v1, v2);

    Timer makingVertices;
    makingVertices.start();
    size_t n = 1e3;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vertex>> vertices(n);
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        vertices[i] = g.addVertex();
        vertices[i]->x = i;
    }
    makingVertices.stop();

    Timer makingEdges;
    makingEdges.start();
    for (auto v1 : vertices) {
        for (auto v2: vertices) {
            if (v1!=v2) {
                g.addEdge(v1, v2);
            }
        }
    }
    makingEdges.stop();

    Timer deletingVertices;
    deletingVertices.start();
    for (auto vert : vertices) {
        g.deleteVertex(vert);
    }
    deletingVertices.stop();

    wholeProgram.stop();

    std::cout << "Making Verts: " << makingVertices.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Making edges: " << makingEdges.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Deleting verts: " << deletingVertices.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Whole program: " << wholeProgram.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

And the timings (with '-O3') are:

```
Making Verts: 0
Making edges: 270
Deleting verts: 188
Whole program: 458
```

(In my actual code base, the deleting of the vertices is actually around 90% of the time to create the graph).

How can I optimize this code to reduce the time to delete vertices (And also I guess optimize the creation of edges, as this is also slow)?

The full code to run this example is:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class Timer
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        m_StartTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        m_bRunning = true;
    }
    
    void stop()
    {
        m_EndTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        m_bRunning = false;
    }
    
    double elapsedMilliseconds()
    {
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> endTime;
        
        if(m_bRunning)
        {
            endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        }
        else
        {
            endTime = m_EndTime;
        }
        
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - m_StartTime).count();
    }
    
    double elapsedSeconds()
    {
        return elapsedMilliseconds() / 1000.0;
    }
private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_StartTime;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_EndTime;
    bool                                               m_bRunning = false;
};

struct Deref {
    /**
     * @brief Function to dereference the pointer when hashing elements in a hashmap of shared pointers
     * 
     */
    struct Hash {
        template <typename T> std::size_t operator()(std::shared_ptr<T> const& p) const
        {
            return std::hash<T>()(*p);
        }
        template <typename T> std::size_t operator()(T const & p) const
        {
            return std::hash<T>(p);
        }
    };
    /**
     * @brief Function to dereference the pointer when comparing elements in a hashmap of shared pointers
     * 
     */
    struct Compare {
        template <typename T> bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<T> const& a, std::shared_ptr<T> const& b) const
        {
            return *a == *b;
        }
        template <typename T> bool operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const
        {
            return a == b;
        }
    };
};

struct Vertex {
    int x;
    bool operator==(const Vertex& b) {
        return x==b.x;
    }
};

template<> struct std::hash<Vertex> {
    std::size_t operator()(Vertex const& v) const noexcept {
        return std::hash<int>()(v.x);
    }
};


struct Edge {
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr;
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to;
    double weight;
    Edge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr_in, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to_in) : fr(fr_in), to(to_in) {};
};


class Graph{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> addVertex() {
        auto new_vertex = std::make_shared<Vertex>();
        mAdjacencyList[new_vertex] = {};
        return new_vertex;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Edge> addEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to) {
        auto edge = std::make_shared<Edge>(fr, to);
        mAdjacencyList[fr][to] = edge;
        return edge;
    }
    void deleteVertex(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> v) {
        mAdjacencyList.erase(v);
        for (auto& [key, val] : mAdjacencyList) {
            val.erase(v);
        }
    };
private:
    std::unordered_map<
        std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
        std::unordered_map<
            std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
            std::shared_ptr<Edge>,
            Deref::Hash,
            Deref::Compare
        >,
        Deref::Hash,
        Deref::Compare
    > mAdjacencyList;
};

int main() {
    Timer wholeProgram;
    wholeProgram.start();

    Graph g;
    auto v1 = g.addVertex();
    auto v2 = g.addVertex();
    auto e = g.addEdge(v1, v2);

    Timer makingVertices;
    makingVertices.start();
    size_t n = 1e3;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vertex>> vertices(n);
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        vertices[i] = g.addVertex();
        vertices[i]->x = i;
    }
    makingVertices.stop();

    Timer makingEdges;
    makingEdges.start();
    for (auto v1 : vertices) {
        for (auto v2: vertices) {
            if (v1!=v2) {
                g.addEdge(v1, v2);
            }
        }
    }
    makingEdges.stop();

    Timer deletingVertices;
    deletingVertices.start();
    for (auto vert : vertices) {
        g.deleteVertex(vert);
    }
    deletingVertices.stop();

    wholeProgram.stop();

    std::cout << "Making Verts: " << makingVertices.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Making edges: " << makingEdges.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Deleting verts: " << deletingVertices.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Whole program: " << wholeProgram.elapsedMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

And to run it, you can [view it online](https://godbolt.org/z/d7EWzxYjT)

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: I think my code doesnt fully explain why I need to prune the edges, I might rewrite the question to emphisise why I am doing it. 

Thanks for editing the title, the site was being weird for me and not letting me find my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid having to loop over all vertices

In `deleteVertex()`, you loop over all of `mAdjacencyList`. However, in sparse graphs that means you unnecessarily visit a lot of vertices that weren't a neighbor of the one you deleted.

You could consider always storing edge information going both ways, but indicating in some way which directions were actually added to the graph and which not. That way, you can always efficiently look up which other vertices have an edge to a given vertex. For example, make two adjacency sets: one for incoming edges, one for outgoing ones:

```
class Graph{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> addVertex() {
        return std::make_shared<Vertex>();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Edge> addEdge(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> fr, std::shared_ptr<Vertex> to) {
        auto edge = std::make_shared<Edge>(fr, to);
        mOutEdges[fr][to] = edge;
        mInEdges[to][fr] = edge;
        return edge;
    }

    void deleteVertex(std::shared_ptr<Vertex> v) {
        // Find neighbors using v's incoming edge list,
        // and delete those neighbors' in/out edges from/to v.
        for (auto& [neighbor, inEdges]: mInEdges[v]) {
            inEdges.erase(v);
            mOutEdges[neighbor].erase(v);
        }

        // Somewhat bad naming:
        // this doesn't delete edges, but rather the vertex v.
        mInEdges.erase(v);
        mOutEdges.erase(v)
    };

private:
    using AdjacencySet = std::unordered_map<
        std::shared_ptr<Vertex>,
        std::unordered_map<…>,
        Deref::Hash,
        Deref::Compare
    >;

    AdjacencySet mInEdges;
    AdjacencySet mOutEdges;
};
```

## Handle bulk updates

One reason deleting the vertices is slow in your `main()` is because you delete them all one by one. If you know you are going to delete all of them, you could just do `mAdjacencySets.clear()`.

If you delete only some of the vertices, it might still be interesting to see if you can optimize this. Consider that if you delete two vertices that are neighbors of each other, you don't have to erase from each other's adjacency list.

## Rethink the way you store the graph

The problem with your code is that the way you store your graph is very unoptimal. While operations on `std::unordered_map` are \$O(1)\$ (amortized!), that doesn't mean these operations are cheap and fast. `std::shared_ptr` in particular has some costs you have to consider: every time it is copied it needs to do atomic reference counting. Furthermore, it will allocate objects on the heap that might not be layed out optimally in memory. The `std::unordered_map`s will also allocate memory for each element they store, again not guaranteed to be nicely consecutively in memory.

Ideally, the vertices and their adjacency lists are stored in compact arrays, and vertices are labelled by their position in the array they are stored in:

```
struct Graph {
    using VertexID = std::size_t;

    struct Vertex {
        …
        std::vector<VertexID> neighbors;
    };

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices; 

    VertexID addVertex() {
        vertices.emplace_back();
        return vertices.size() - 1;
    }

    void addEdge(VertexID from, VertexID to) {
        vertices[from].neighbors.push_back(to);
    }
};
```

Of course, the above is nice when only adding vertices and edges, removing them is problematic. There are ways to fix that; you could make `vertices` store `std::optional<Vertex>`es, so you can "delete" one without moving the other vertices, which would otherwise invalidate their indices. Scanning linearly through `neighbors` might sound slow but given the much better memory locality it can be more efficient if the graph is not very dense. You can make it logarithmic by keeping the neighbors sorted (in C++23 you could do that by using [std::flat_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/flat_set)). For dense graphs you might thing about using `std::unordered_set<VertexID>`, or you could consider storing adjacency information in a `std::vector<bool>`, where every bit represents whether another vertex is a neighbor or not. The latter is \$O(1)\$ again.

Another issue with your code is that you store a lot of redundant information. An `Edge` does not need to have `fr` and `to` members; that information is already encoded in the keys of the `std::unordered_map`s.

## Use of smart pointers

As already mentioned, `std::shared_ptr` has some overhead. You should only use it if you really need shared ownership of some object stored on the heap. For a graph however you should be able to have one container own the vertices it stores, and everything else just has a reference or pointer to those vertices. At most you need a `std::unique_ptr`, but since `std::unordered_map` already allocates memory for the objects it stores, even that shouldn't be necessary. So you could write:

```
std::unordered_map<Vertex, std::unordered_map<Vertex*, Edge>> mAdjacencyList;
```

## Make vertices store their own neighbor lists

The declaration of `mAdjacencyList` looks quite complex. Consider storing the list of neighbors of a vertex in `Vertex` itself; this would simplify the code a lot:

```
struct Edge {
    double weight;
};

struct Vertex {
    int x;
    std::unordered_map<Vertex*, Edge> neighbors;
};

std::unordered_set<Vertex> vertices;
```

Of course, you still need to make sure the objects can be hashed if they are going to be stored in these containers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I am new to C++ and I love it, but it is very hard. One of the reasons why I was using pointers everywhere is because I am not sure what the lifetime of these objects is, as I am binding them in Python and I get confused what happens when I have calculated the shortest path, and get a vector/list of edges, and then discard the graph object. Do I just need to pass by copy? What if I want to let the python program take ownership and modify the edge/vertex object?

Comment: `If you know you are going to delete all of them, you could just do mAdjacencySets.clear().` In my problem, I need to delete vertices with no outward edges (apart from vertices with connections to the destination node), and keep on doing this until every vertex has a path, so it doesn't clear the graph (I just made it as an example)

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++/Python interoperability, so you would have to figure out how to pass ownership yourself. It is true that you have to think more about ownership yourself in C++. `std::shared_ptr` is indeed a safe option in that regard, but you lose some performance if unnecessary. I know you said you want to delete specific nodes in the question, but then your code just deletes all of them, and you measure the time of that. It would be better to make a more realistic example and benchmark that.